# Terminal says 'Broken package' when using apt-get to install phpMyAdmin

Tags: command-line, package-management, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tried to install phpMyAdmin using the *sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin* command> The terminal says that there are "uninstallable" dependencies, therefore the package is broken.Perhaps the following copy-paste from the terminal will explain the full view:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
[sudo] password for sam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-mysqli but it is not installable
              Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

What do you suggest on this problem?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? What happens if you try to install `php5-mysql`?

Answer (score 1):

Only with that app, or with everything you try to install?

You can try:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I managed to install the package and all of its dependencies. The problem was that I wasn't updating repositories for a while.